# Find information NOT in a reference sheet in another worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have two worksheets, one is my reference sheet with a list of products.  I have other worksheets with many of the same products, but also some new products not in my reference sheet.  I'd like to find the list of products NOT included in my reference sheet that exist on my other sheets.

For example

Reference Sheet:

```
RED
BLUE
GREEN
BLACK
WHITE
```

Other Sheet

```
RED 
CYAN
BLUE
WHITE
YELLOW
GREEN
```

I don't need to know that the other sheet doesn't have black, but do need to know that it includes CYAN and YELLOW.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If both of your sheets have the list in the A column, simply type this formula into cell B2 of the "other" sheet: `=VLOOKUP(A2;"Reference sheet"!A:A;1)`  and copy it down to the rest of the rows

Comment: Are you using Excel for MS Office 365?

Comment: Conditional formatting?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:
[image]

and formulas:
[image]

Here is formula from cell F3: =IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(E3,B$1:B$8,0)),0,1)
and formula from cell B10: =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A10,$D$3:$E$21,2,FALSE),"")

Comment: Maybe include the formulas as text?

Comment: Yes, the formulae need to be text in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel for MS365, you can use the FILTER function with ISNA and XMATCH to return a dynamic list of any new/missing values in your Reference Sheet. Using the sample data provided, if the values are in column A in both sheets, the following formula will return {"CYAN";"YELLOW"} in a spilled array:

```
=FILTER('Other Sheet'!A2:A7, ISNA(XMATCH('Other Sheet'!A2:A7, 'Reference Sheet'!A2:A6)), "No new products")
```

If the "Other Sheet" contains multiple records of each product, you can also use the UNIQUE function to return a simplified list:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER('Other Sheet'!A2:A7, ISNA(XMATCH('Other Sheet'!A2:A7, 'Reference Sheet'!A2:A6)), "No new products"))
```

If you need to compare the Reference Sheet to multiple "Other Sheets", you can compile a complete list of products from the other sheets using the VSTACK function. For example:

```
=LET(
   arr, UNIQUE(VSTACK('Other Sheet1'!A2:A7, 'Other Sheet2'!A2:A9)),
   FILTER(arr, ISNA(XMATCH(arr, 'Reference Sheet'!A2:A6)), "No new products")
)
```

Again, please note, these methods will only work with Excel for MS365.